# Make copy of subtree containing 500k nodes and 1m relations in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am evaluating neo4j. I created some random data to compare with other dbs. The data represents a tree structure with 10k, 100k and 1m nodes. There are two relationship types, the hierarchical one, and a connection chain relation like a linked list.

One of the operations that I want to test is to make a copy of a subtree. This operation is done in three steps (copy nodes, copy relations, connect to target). The operation works fine for 10k and 100k tree. But for the biggest example with a copy tree of 500k neo4j never comes back.

The browser shows that it is getting reconnected and nothing happens. I think 500k nodes should not be that much. The test data in cvs files is around 300mb.

What am I doing wrong?

1: copy nodes

```
match (r {`domain key` : 'unit-B2'})-[:isPredecessorOf*0..]->(n:`T-Base`) 
with n as map create (copy:`T-Base`) 
set copy = map, copy.`domain key` = map.`domain key` + '-copy'  
with map, copy 
create (copy)-[:isCopyOf]->(map)
```

2: copy relations

```
match (s {`domain key` : 'unit-B2'})-[:isPredecessorOf*0..]->(n)
with collect(n) as st, s
match (s)-[:isPredecessorOf*0..]->(t)-[r:`isPredecessorOf`]->(x)
where x in st
with startNode(r) as s, endNode(r) as d
match (s)<-[:isCopyOf]-(source), (d)<-[:isCopyOf]-(dest)
with source, dest
create (source)-[:isPredecessorOf]->(dest)

match (s {`domain key` : 'unit-B2'})-[:isPredecessorOf*0..]->(n)
with collect(n) as st, s
match (s)-[:isPredecessorOf*0..]->(t)-[r:`isConnectedTo`]->(x)
where x in st
with startNode(r) as s, endNode(r) as d
match (s)<-[:isCopyOf]-(source), (d)<-[:isCopyOf]-(dest)
with source, dest
create (source)-[:isConnectedTo]->(dest)
```

3: connect root of copy tree to target node

```
match (source{`domain key`:'unit-B1'}), (dest{`domain key`:'unit-B2-copy'})
create (source)-[:isPredecessorOf]->(dest)
```

Comment: How do you run Neo4j? It's probably just a memory configuration issue for transactional memory.

Comment: It is run as a windows service. The server has 18gb memory.
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=10g
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=10g
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=6g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How do you run Neo4j? It's probably just a memory configuration issue for transactional memory. For 1M records you need about 4G heap config.
2. you should use a label for r and s
3. separate your 2nd statement into two statements.

If you have to do larger transactional updates, you can install the apoc procedures and use apoc.periodic.iterate to execute updates in batches.

e.g.

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate('
match (r:Label {`domain key` : 'unit-B2'})-[:isPredecessorOf*0..]->(n:`T-Base`) 
return distinct n as map
','
create (copy:`T-Base`) 
set copy = map, copy.`domain key` = map.`domain key` + '-copy'  
with map, copy 
create (copy)-[:isCopyOf]->(map)
',{batchSize:10000,iterateList:true})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, apoc.periodic.iterate did the trick, the second step was already executed as two statements, but I converted it to periodic also. Is the folowing configuration sufficiant for the amount of data: dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=10g, dbms.memory.heap.max_size=10g, dbms.memory.pagecache.size=6g? As a result from my tests I can assume that neo4j cannot cope with transactions that are as large as 500000 modified objects? I mean sometimes it works and sometimes not. Nevertheless batching the data works for now, thanks.